# Illegal Chars in recursive Directory traversal

Tags: powershell, webdav, directory, subdirectory, powershell-3.0

im trying to *count the amount of files in folders recursivly* on a mounted WebDav Drive.
Following Script works if there are no illegal Char's in Path or Filenames and like a Charm on my local Disk.
But i have got quite a lot of **illegal Char's** on that mounted drive (Linux)

I tried to add `$ErrorActionPreference = "SilentlyContinue"` to the start of the Script so that even if theres is an Error it Continues.

So I added `Where-Object {Test-Path $_.FullName -isValid}` to catch illegal Path's.

It still breaks on the illegal Char's..

Next idear was to get the illegal char's from my System and filter the Path's which are containing them.

```
$illChars = [RegEx]::Escape([String][System.IO.Path]::GetInvalidFileNameChars())
```

looked sweet to me so i can easily put a `-match $illChars` somewhere.
But still, no hope.

I think the Error gets thrown and breaks the Pipe on the `Get-ChildItem $path` before i can even check the path (im really new to PowerShell Scripting so no idear if im right or wrong)

**My big question is: How can i catch that Error?**

**Update:**

The Error gets thrown if ther are illega Filenames in `$Files = @(Get-ChildItem -File $_.FullName)`

The exact error message is

```
Get-ChildItem : Illegales Zeichen im Pfad.
In ***** count-files.ps1:12 Zeichen:15
+             $Files = @(Get-ChildItem -File $_)
+                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (L:\flash\fs\trailer:String) [Get-ChildItem], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DirArgumentError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand

Get-ChildItem : Illegales Zeichen im Pfad.
In ***** \count-files.ps1:6 Zeichen:1
+ Get-ChildItem $path -recurse -exclude ".DAV" -Directory |
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (L:\flash\fs\trailer:String) [Get-ChildItem], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DirArgumentError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
```

**Update 2**

Still same Error, but **now the Script Continues. Yay.**
Is it possible to eliminate the Error completly?

**UPDATE 3**

New **Error "Path-format"**
and Script stops again
Thinking about using diruse.exe...

```
Get-ChildItem : Das angegebene Pfadformat wird nicht unterstützt.
In D:\workspace\videoRename\count-files.ps1:13 Zeichen:15
+             $Files = @(Get-ChildItem -File $_.FullName | where { $_.Name -notmatch $patte ...
+                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-ChildItem], NotSupportedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.NotSupportedException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand

Get-ChildItem : Das angegebene Pfadformat wird nicht unterstützt.
In D:\workspace\videoRename\count-files.ps1:7 Zeichen:1
+ Get-ChildItem $path -recurse -exclude ".DAV" -Directory | where { $_.Name -notma ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-ChildItem], NotSupportedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.NotSupportedException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
```

Ok, there is something like `GetInvalidPathChars`
lets check the paths...

**Update 4.1**
Still throws both Errors *Illegal Path and File* and stops at Path.
The Else(illegal Path) wont get called, even on path error.

```
#$ErrorActionPreference = "SilentlyContinue"
$path="L:\"
$illName = "[{0}]" -f ([Regex]::Escape([String][System.IO.Path]::GetInvalidFileNameChars()))
$illPath = "[{0}]" -f ([Regex]::Escape([String][System.IO.Path]::GetInvalidPathChars()))

Get-ChildItem $path -recurse -exclude ".DAV" -Directory | where { $_.Name -notmatch $illName } | where { $_.FullName -notmatch $illPath } |
    foreach-object {
        write-host $_
        if((Test-Path $_ -isValid) -and (Test-Path $_.FullName -isValid) -and ($_.FullName -notmatch $illPath) ){
            write-host $_
            $FolderDepth = ($_.FullName.Split("\\") | measure-object).Count - 1
            $Files = @(Get-ChildItem -File $_.FullName | where {Test-Path $_ -isValid} | where { $_.Name -notmatch $illName } )
            $Size = 0
            $Files | % {$Size = $Size + $_.Length}
            New-Object PsObject -Property @{
                'Directory' = $_.FullName
                'Files' = $Files.Count
                'Depth' = $FolderDepth
                'Size' = $Size
            }
        }else {
            write-host "Error in Folder:" $_.FullName
            New-Object PsObject -Property @{
                'Directory' = $_.FullName
                'Files' = -1
                'Depth' = -1
                'Size' = -1
            }
        }
    } |
export-csv -notypeinformation -Delimiter ";" -encoding default -path test.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't test this easily from here but something like the following?

```
Get-ChildItem $path -recurse -Directory |
    foreach-object {
    if((Test-Path $_ -isValid) -and ($_ -notMatch ".DAV")) {
```

Following your update, give this a go... at the top of your script insert:

```
$pattern = "[{0}]" -f ([Regex]::Escape([String][System.IO.Path]::GetInvalidFileNameChars()))
```

Then amend where you populate $files to:

```
$Files = @(Get-ChildItem -File $_.FullName  -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | 
    ? { $_.Name -notmatch $pattern })
```

Comment: Thx for the Answer, but it breaks on the same position. Im running again with error ouput so i can be more specific.